# How to correct mat-icon preventing `text-transform` on sibling element

Tags: html, css, sass, angular-material

I have a button that includes a `mat-icon`. It conditionally renders with an `is-text` class, and if that's present, I override the `text-transform` property for the button from `uppercase` to `capitalize`. However the `capitalize` property does not apply (in my opinion) correctly. That is, in the example below I should have:

> Filter/Sort

where in fact what is rendered is:

> filter/Sort

Markup:

```
<button class="button is-text">
  <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  <label class="label">
    <span class="span">filter/sort</span>
  </label>
</button>
```

SCSS:

```
.button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  &.is-text {
    .label .span{
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }
  }
}
```

If the `mat-icon` is removed, the capitalization renders correctly, but I don't want to do that.

#### What is the correct way to apply the `capitalize` property to only the `.span` element?

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngvi2b?file=src%2Fapp%2Ficon-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `display: inline-block` to the span fixes the problem.

```
.button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  &.is-text {
    .label .span{
      text-transform: capitalize;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
}
```